# How to set an image as title in all navigation bars in swift?

Tags: swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I need to know if it is possible to add an image as title on all navigation controllers, this mean, that every controller that had a navigation bar had the same image title.

I used the next code to set an image as title in the navigation bar, but I have to set it on every viewController, the idea its for example set it on AppDelegate as UINavigationBar.appereance() or similar.

```
let imageView         = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "my_image.png")!)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

let titleView         = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 107, height: 30))
 imageView.frame       = titleView.bounds
titleView.addSubview(imageView) 

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

So the idea is to set this image as the default title for every controller,  that way I will just need to configure it one time.

It is that posible? If not, What possible solution do you think that I can apply ?

Comment: do you want to add image as navigation bar title?

Answer (score 1):

The title view is a property of each view controller, not the navigation bar or navigation controller.

So start with a UIViewController subclass whose navigation item has this title view, and make all your other view controllers be subclasses of that.

Comment: I tried but the problem continue when a need to set it on a UITableViewController or UICollectionViewController @matt

Comment: Yes, then the same thing: you'll have to subclass UITableViewController and UICollectionViewController and make your actual table and collection view controllers be subclasses of those subclasses. So you'll have your code repeated in three places, these will be tiny snippets of code so it's not a big deal.

Comment: Another possibility is to _inject_ a method into a UIViewController, but then you would have to remember to _call_ that method in every single view controller.

Comment: Thats exactly want I doing, I create an extension of ViewController but well I have to called everywhere @matt

Comment: Well, those are your choices. Take them or leave them. You cannot magically do this thru the appearance proxy.

Comment: Ok, thanks I just wanted to know if there was a way

Comment: Yes, I understand! The problem here is that you cannot use an extension to override a method, so you cannot inject code into all UIViewControllers and have that code run in some automatic way.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code,

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

if this not works please share the screenshot.

Comment: Can you please share screenshot, what you want actually.

Comment: I can't show it on an image. I want to set you answer as default, so I don't have to put that code on every view, just configure one time